# GPS compass bearing a

Tags: php, gps, compass-geolocation, bearing

In the past few weeks i got a new project where i need to collect GPS data from an on board unit and place it on a map. Actually everything works fine but i have some problem with the compass bearing. In some case it turns -180 degrees but a few moments later it works fine. 
I use the following code:

```
//difference in longitudinal coordinates
   $dLon = deg2rad($lon2) - deg2rad($lon1);

   //difference in the phi of latitudinal coordinates
   $dPhi = log(tan(deg2rad($lat2) / 2 + pi() / 4) / tan(deg2rad($lat1) / 2 + pi() / 4));

   //we need to recalculate $dLon if it is greater than pi
   if(abs($dLon) > pi()) {
      if($dLon > 0) {
         $dLon = (2 * pi() - $dLon) * -1;
      }
      else {
         $dLon = 2 * pi() + $dLon;
      }
   }
   //return the angle, normalized
   return (rad2deg(atan2($dLon, $dPhi)) + 360) % 360;
```

At some point i thougt that my coordinates are not accurate but that is not the problem.

The GPS coord. formats are the following: 1234.4567;8910.1112

What do you think, what could be wrong?

Thank you for your aswers!

Regards, Gábor

Comment: Can you provide a sequence of data that shows the compass bearing turning -180 and then returning to normal?

Comment: A feed from a static gps will have jitter, the location will bounce around within a range from fractions of a meter to >10 meters depending on conditions.

Comment: Thanks, actually this was/is the problem. Thank your for your answers!